# a generic dialog load routine

Tags: .net, winforms, subroutine

i have alot of dialog in my winform app and i do this for each one of them when i need to load

```
Dim frm As New Settings
        frm.ShowDialog()
        frm = Nothing
```

i was thinking if its possible to have a routine like this

```
sub LoadDialog(byval item as form)
' code to load specific form passd here
end sub
```

then i call like this `loadDialog(customersDialog)`. where the CustomerDialog is a form

an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a [generic procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235246%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to handle this:

```
Public Shared Sub LoadAndShowDialog(Of T As {Form, New})()
    Dim frm As New T
    frm.ShowDialog() 
End Function
```

You could then call this as:

```
LoadAndShowDialog(Of Settings)()
```

Comment: thanks very much, can i add this to the sub without any effect `frm = Nothing`

Comment: @Smith Yes - but it's not necessary.  `frm` is local, so it'll automatically be set to `Nothing` when the Sub ends.

Answer (score 0):

All forms inherit from Form right? Below should be fine. And if you need something from that form store it in the tag and you can retrieve it after the form closes.

```
Public Function LoadForm(MyForm As Form) As Object
    MyForm.ShowDialog()
    Return MyForm.Tag
End Function
```